# Removing extra files after uninstalling a clickonce application

Tags: c#-4.0, clickonce, uninstallation

I have a project that uses clickonce to generate the setup.exe. During the run time my program create some extra files like "Log" and "Attachments" inside the User Folder. However, those folders are not removed when I perform an uninstall of the clickonce application from the ARP. These remaining files are interfering the next install.

I know that click once does not support for adding custom action to install or uninstall. I am wondering if is there is a way that I can remove those extra file programmingly after performing uninstall?

One way I have tried was to create a cleanup script and added it as a bootstrapper package to pre-requisite of the click once project. That worked in a way that every time before a new product was installed, the previous dirty data had been removed. However, this messed up the upgrade case.

Any ideas on how to remove the extra files that left by clickonce uninstallation?

Thank you

JS

Comment: Are the extra files names known at install time?  If so, can you simply supply empty files to be installed so that the uninstaller will delete them?

Comment: For logs the file name is fixed, however, the attachment name is generated in random form. But Attachment folder is a know path

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do anything when uninstalling a ClickOnce application other than uninstall the ClickOnce application.

Have you considered putting the files in the ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory ? Then they will be removed when the application is unisntalled.

If the files are part of the project, you can set the type to Data in the Application Files dialog, and it will automatically place them in the data directory when deploying.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Robin. We have some database files that shared by multi-windows users.  because we want to share the data between different windows users on the same machine. I guess one possible way to do it would be, build a .msi installer and embeded it into a clickonce setup.exe. in that way we may have custom install/uninstall actions. but then I need to  worry about the upgrade case again...

Comment: I have no idead why, but for me, this folder (ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory) does not get removed

Answer (score 0):

This solution works on multiple re-installations (clean), however it doesn't remove the data on last uninstall or until the next installation takes place.

Stil there is no custom action place on uninstall to remove the files beyond clickonce scope.

Leave a file in to ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory.

On startup, see if the file exists on conditions network deployed, firstrun (which resets on upgarde too).. success case, it is a first installation or upgrade. Failure case, the application is been uninstalled and installing again .. now you have a chance to clean up the application data.

If the data is sensitive, you may want to use other solution to remove files on uninstall ( as of now I don't see that Microsoft is given us an option)