# Get access to AppSettings from custom Installer during uninstall (BeforeUninstall)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, setup-deployment, appsettings

I have a VS solution with following structure:

1. Library project (.dll)
2. Application using the #1 library project

I have app.config defined in the application (#2) which defines a `SaveLogsToDirectory` path in appSettings. This value is eventually used by the library project to save the logs generated.

Simple use of api `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SaveLogsToDirectory"]` 
in the library fetches the value from app.config.

Library project has a custom *System.Configuration.Install.Installer* class defined. When the application is uninstalled from windows via Control Panel, I would like the logs generated at path *SaveLogsToDirectory* to be deleted. Issue is the below code returns null only and only during the uninstall execution

`System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SaveLogsToDirectory"]`

One of the other approaches I tried was using `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())`

but during uninstall the api `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` returns reference to library project.

I need help on how I can access the application assembly from library during uninstall? One thing to mention is that I cannot provide a class path defined in application to OpenExeConfiguration api since the dll can be used by any other application and that other application may not have that class defined.

Comment: The installer knows the install directory. The problem is, it doesn't know the config file name. As an option you can store the setting in the config file of your dll. This way the installer will know about config file name as well (yourdll.config) and can use it.

Answer (score 1):

As an option you can store the dll settings in config file of the dll rather than config file of the application.

Then you can easily use `OpenExeConfiguration` and pass the dll address as parameter and read the settings.

To make it easier and harmonic to reading from app settings, you can create a like following and use it this way: `LibrarySettings.AppSettings["something"]`. Here is the a simple implementation:

```
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Reflection;
public class LibrarySettings
{
    private static NameValueCollection appSettings;
    public static NameValueCollection AppSettings
    {
        get
        {
            if (appSettings == null)
            {
                appSettings = new NameValueCollection();
                var assemblyLocation = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
                var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(assemblyLocation);
                foreach (var key in config.AppSettings.Settings.AllKeys)
                    appSettings.Add(key, config.AppSettings.Settings[key].Value);
            }
            return appSettings;
        }
    }
}
```

**Notes:** Just in case you don't want to rely on `Assembly.ExecutingAssembly` when uninstall is running, you can easily use [`TARGETDIR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/targetdir) property which specifies the installation directory. It's enough to set `CustomActionData` property of the custom action to `/path="[TARGETDIR]\"`, then inside the installer class, you can easily get it using `Context.Parameters["path"]`. Then in the other hand you know the name of the dll file and using `OpenMappedExeConfiguration` by passing config file address as parameter, read the settings.

To setup a custom installer action and getting target directory, you may find this step-by-step answer useful:[Visual Studio Setup Project - Remove files created at runtime when uninstall](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46787462/3110834).