# Is there a way to use delete all files in Visual Studio Installer for a C# application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, windows-installer

Is there a way to get rid of all files. I install the files at install but post-install I edit them. I am not sure if I need to use a custom action (of which I do not know how to use those) or what. Any suggestions? The file types are .XML files that are empty on install, and then added to during setup, which is a windows form I created to make my own setup page.

Comment: Files that get installed by the windows-installer are normally removed at uninstall. Which version of Visual Studio is this?

Comment: It is VS2019 and True, but I like I said it may be due to the fact that I am editing them.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46786297/578411

Comment: Are you talking baout stuff in the Programm or the User Profile directory?

Comment: They are in application files folder.

Comment: @rene That is a good try, but when I add the class library project it will not let me add the reference to the installer assembly.